# Does anybody knows how to do an if statement in assembly for Atmega328p?

Tags: if-statement, assembly

i need your help, I don't know how to write an if statement in assembly, for ATmega328p, please help me!

Comment: what did you see when you disassembled say some compiled C code?  or when you read the docs for the instruction set which you have to have before learning asm?

Comment: Its the same as any other assembly language: use a conditional branch to skip over the then-part in the case that the if-condition is false.

Comment: no it is not compiled with c code, and I just read the instructions set and it doesn't say what I need to learn before asm. This is the link for my data sheet, so you can maybe understand what I need. thank you very much, I really appreciate your answer. https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf

Comment: i have had so many problems learning assembly so I don't really know how to do it in any assembly language. I don't know if you have any examples that you can show to me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this processor has what are called condition codes.  Certain instructions set them and other read them.  Conditional branching is done by using add, subtract or compare instructions to set the condition codes, and then a conditional branch instruction to test for the desired condition.  We use conditional branching to accomplish the flow of control for an if-then statement.

The basic idea is that we want the processor to skip past the then-part in the case that the C condition is false.

Regular C code:

```
if ( i < 10 ) {
    printf ("i < 10!");   // then part "fires" when i < 10 is true
}
```

Pseudo C code that does the above if-then, but using labels, and conditional branching  like assembly:

```
    if ( i >= 10 ) goto pastThen;   # this is a conditional branch that skips the then part 
                                    # when i < 10 is false
                                    #  ! (i<10) or "(i<10) is false" is the same as  i>=10
    printf ("i < 10!");
pastThen:
```

We would translate that into assembly by writing some assembly to compare `i` with `10`, which will set the condition codes, and then use a branch-greater-or-equal to the label such as `pastThen`.  Something like this (but this is still pseudo code):

```
    load r0,i
    compare r0,#10
    bge pastThen
    ... # code to call printf ("i < 10!");
pastThen:
```

Using conditional branches (and the occasional unconditional branch) we can create while, for, and repeat loops, if-then statements, and if-then-else — all the control structures of *structured programming*.

Once you know this you will be able to read assembly better.  You might check out godbolt.org where there are compilers to experiment with.  So, you can feed the compiler a small function in C and see what kind of code it generates for the statements and expressions you provide them with.  They have an Arduino Mega compiler but I don't know if that is compatible with your chip, though it might give you a better idea of how to go about your specific if statement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but I have a question, what is bee and past then:, in the assembly code? thank yoy